# Just installed Anaconda how do I start spyder ide or pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to Python but an experienced programmer. Believe it or not after reading the documentation on installing pycharm and spider i am left wondering how do I startup the ide? I installed Anaconda with Pycharm and then did pip of spyder but believe it or not there is nothing in the documentation that says how to startup the ide applications. Just how to install them and then once the app is started. How about starting up an Python IDE? How do you do this. I am on a Mac. I did the obvious like check app folder. python pycharm etc

```
 (base) coffee:~ Steven$ conda install pycharm
 Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
 Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with 
 flexible solve.
 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
 Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with 
 flexible solve.

 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from 
 current channels:

 - pycharm

  Current channels:

   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

   To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
```

you're
      looking for, navigate to

```
  https://anaconda.org

  and use the search bar at the top of the page.


     ( .base) coffee:~ Steven$ pycharm
     -bash: pycharm: command not found
    (base) coffee:~ Steven$ pycharm
    -bash: pycharm: command not found
   (base) coffee:~ Steven$ pip pycharm
   ERROR: unknown command "pycharm"
  (base) coffee:~ Steven$ pip install pycharm
   Collecting pycharm
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
   pycharm (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycharm
    (base) coffee:~ Steven$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start Spyder, type the name **spyder in a terminal or at the Command Prompt**. The Python 2.7 version of Anaconda also includes a graphical Launcher application that enables you to start IPython Notebook, IPython QTConsole, and Spyder with a single click.

Comment: Ok, how about pycharm why dos it not start in the same manner. I actually saw Pycharm during the install of Anaconda but unlike Spyder it does not come up when I type its name at the command prompt.

Comment: you have to download Pycharm to use, as you can use conda  Interpreter later while creating a new project in Pycharm IDE

Comment: After installing anaconda install the community edition of Pycharm along with re recommended JRE, after pycharm installed the first thing we shall do is create a project, choose an interpreter (in this case, choose anaconda), Select Interpreter choose your anaconda path (you can do which conda in the terminal to see where anaconda is) and click create, Now create a new project i.e .py file and execute your code. Cheers

Comment: Thanks hope this clear explanation makes it into the documentation